# AngularJS- Prevent all button instances from opening

Tags: angularjs, scope, toggle

I currently have a list of toggle buttons that trigger drop down content. To give these buttons their functionality I have a toggle function in the controller. I believe that my issue is occurring because the buttons are all sharing the same scope. When I click to open one button, they all open, when I close one, they all close.

Assuming this is a scope issue, how would I go about giving each of these their own scope so that only one button will open at a time?

Thanks!

My markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <a ng-click="toggle()">Drop Down</a>
            <ul ng-show="isVisible">
                <li ng-repeat="thing in things">
                    <a ng-href="{{something.url}}">{{something.text}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My controller (the relevant part):

```
function NotificationController($scope) {

    // I toggle the value of isVisible.
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.isVisible = ! $scope.isVisible;
    };

    // Default the blocks to be visible.
    $scope.isVisible = false;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` already creates a new scope for each item, but `isVisible` is defined on the parent scope so the scopes all fall back to that.

You could add a property 'isVisible' to each item and add an index parameter to toggle() so it knows which one to switch. For example:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a ng-click="toggle($index)">Drop Down</a>
        <ul ng-show="item.isVisible">
            <li ng-repeat="thing in things">
                <a ng-href="{{something.url}}">{{something.text}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function NotificationController($scope) {

  // I toggle the value of isVisible.
  $scope.toggle = function(index) {
      $scope.items[index].isVisible = ! $scope.items[index].isVisible;
  };

  // Default the blocks to be visible.
  $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isVisible = false;
  });

}
```

Comment: Better yet, if  you don't need `toggle` to do anything more complicated, you can just do the simple toggle logic in the template: `<a ng-click="item.isVisible = !item.isVisible">`

Comment: What would be the best way to set up the drop downs so that only one of them could be open at a time?

Comment: I'd introduce an 'activeIndex' variable on the scope. Then `<a ng-click="activeIndex = $index">` and `<ul ng-show="$index == activeIndex">`

Comment: Another functionality I would like to add would be to have the drop menus toggling off when you click anywhere outside of the element. To achieve this I plan on using a stopPropagation directive. Instead of using an activeIndex, could I include it in the directive? Sorry, still relatively new to Javascript/AngularJS.